# remove BadgeNumber from other app (jailbreak iphone)

Tags: objective-c, badge, uiapplication

I have 2 apps that I want to connect together, I want to control the "BagdeNumer" 
will running the other app  sometime to show 1 or sometime show 100 ...

I using this command to control on the Badge in the app im in NOW ..

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1];
```

and in the same time i want to remove the other app Badge number

how can i do it ?

Comment: if you can do it, than you must aquire -somehow- the UIApplication reference to the other app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement an URL scheme for both apps and have the first open the second, the second then removes its own badge number and opens the first again.
Obviously, this wouldn't even require a jailbreak.